# Why do I get no warning when protocol methods are not specified?

Tags: warnings, protocols, xcode4

I'm using Xcode 4, have a simple class interface defined and I added NSTableViewDelegate and NSTableViewDataSource protocols to the interface definition. I.e,
   @interface foo : NSObject < NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource>

In my build settings, I have confirmed that the option "Incomplete Objective-C Protocols" warning is enabled (for Debug/Any Architecture etc) and I should get a compile time warning for the non-optional methods required for the NSTableViewDataSource protocol. However, I get no warnings at all but then at runtime I see the message in the log that the methods aren't defined.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Well at least the delegate protocols are informal so not implementing the methods should still let the code work, meaning you don't have to implement, that's why you don't get warnings for that.

Comment: Some of the methods are required --- that's why I SHOULD get a warning at compile time and not just at runtime.

I am not a fan of just getting runtime warnings if I can have compile time warnings. So the question is whether this is an xcode4 bug or there's something else going on that's stopping warnings from being produced at compile time.

Comment: You can easily find out: Try this in XCode3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at Apple's NSTableView.h, you'll se this:

```
@protocol NSTableViewDataSource <NSObject>
@optional

/* Required Methods
*/
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView;
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)ta    bleColumn row:(NSInteger)row;
...
```

So the comment and the documentation claim that the methods are required, but the code says they're not. The compiler ultimately ignores all comments and documentation happily altogether. ;) Hence you're not getting a compiler warning.

I guess it was their intention to make these two methods required (would make lots of sense), but discovered that lots of their own code relies on it being an informal protocol still. So instead of the headache of changing all the legacy code, I assume they decided to not make them required just yet. I'd expect this to change in Lion though.